# Is there anyway to change discord.py bot's status from streaming to playing?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot and have made a changing status for my bot. Is there anyway that I can change the bot's streaming activity to playing? Here is the code :-

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  client.loop.create_task(status_task())
  print("Bot is Ready!)

async def status_task():
    while True:
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="stream", url='https://www.twitch.tv/discord'))

        await asyncio.sleep(30) 
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="!help", url='https://www.twitch.tv/discord'))
        await asyncio.sleep(30)
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name="a game"))
        await asyncio.sleep(30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `discord.Game`

```py
await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='a game')
```

### References:

- [`discord.Game`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=activity#discord.Game)